# Организация CDN с одновременным обновлением файлов

Tags: многопоточность

В текущем проекте встала необходимость организации полноценного cdn, разнесенного на несколько серверов. Мною была выбрана модель share-(absolutely)-nothing, которая подразумевает, что cdn-сервера в приниципе не имеют гарантированных точек соприкосновения, кроме адресов друг друга (включая базу данных), и с помощью нескольких способов синхронизируют данные в синхронном (при запросе еще не существующего на ноде файла) и асинхронном режимах. Подразумевается, что сервера начинают обновление файла только в том случае, если у источника метка updatedAt (ее значение обозначает момент загрузки пользователем файла, это **не** метка времени получения файла сервером) больше, чем у обновляемого сервера. Текущая архитектура разделяет процесс обновления на два действия: есть один endpoint для обновления данных и другой - для обновления контента, соответствующего данным. И тут и проявляется обычный race condition:

- Пользователь заливает файл Х версии 2 на сервер А
- Сервер А запускает процесс обновления сервера Б, потому что у Б устаревшая метка updatedAt
- Сервер А обновляет данные на сервере Б и начинает медленно заливать файл
- Пользователь успевает залить файл Х версии 3 на сервер С
- Сервер С считает обновленные данные на сервере Б устаревшими и быстро обновляет как данные, так и контент
- Сервер А заканчивает заливать контент, в результате на сервере Б оказывается контент версии 2 и данные версии 3

Есть ли возможность как-то избежать подобной ситуации, сохранив архитектуру и не добавляя клиентских вызовов явного блокирования записи? В принципе, в данный момент в "данные" входит также и md5-чексумма, по которой можно блокировать обновление протухшим контентом, но это все выглядит, как костыли.

P.S. Есть еще вариант с загрузкой временных файлов и введением swap-операции, которая подразумевает передачу id документа, id временного файла и дату аплоада файла, но у меня просто ощущение, что я упускаю какое-то сверхбанальное решение.

P.P.S. Литература по подобным вопросам, конечно, тоже приветствуется. Теорему CAP знаю, дальше сформулировать корректный запрос к гуглу не смог.